# How can i develop an app the records screen video for android kitkat and below?

Tags: android, video, screen, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I wanted to develop an `app` which basically records a screen `video`. It is easily possible in `Lollipop 5.0` using `MediaProjectionManager`. How can i do it in `kitkat` and lower versions of `android` **?**

Comment: It is not possible prior to Android 5.0, except on rooted devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare Then how does usertesting.com do ? I don't want to launch the app in play store.